# what is difference between study of asymtotic and limit?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

In asymptotic, what properties of function we study and in limits what properties of function we study?

Do both describe limiting value of function(s), if yes then what information or knowledge they suppress (or hide or consider unwanted)?

Comment: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/05/23/soft-analysis-hard-analysis-and-the-finite-convergence-principle/

Comment: @Thoth nice link :)

Comment: @Thoth the first table on that page has wrong heading? Table of Soft vs. Hard analysis

Answer (score 1):

A limit is a value. It representants the number you will approach when the parameter of the function you study will grow to a certain level. For example
$$
\frac{1}{x}+4 \underset{ x \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}4
$$
Then the graph of the function is near $4$ as $x$ grows and tends be to be equal to it.

In asymptotic expression, you study how the function behaves around a certain value. And usually compare to another function you know, for example
$$
f(x)=\frac{x^2+3}{x+1}
$$
Observe that it has an asymptot $g :x \mapsto x-1$, it represents the two graphs. As $x$ grows, they behave the same !
[image: Figure of the asymptot]

Note that an asymptotic expression is more precise than just a limit, for example
$$
\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}} \underset{+\infty}{\sim}1-2e^{-2x}
$$
hence we conclude that 
$$
\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}\underset{ x \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}1
$$
But the graph will be as near $1$ as $x \mapsto e^{-2x}$ is near to $0$ when $x$ grows.

Comment: thanks, I don't enough vote to upvote

Comment: Well I can upvote and I thought it was a nice answer.

Comment: Incidentally, p. 2 of this [1999 handout of mine](http://mathforum.org/kb/servlet/JiveServlet/download/206-1874348-6544585-537999/Euler-const.pdf) discusses 4 different types of approximations of functions that show up (at least implicitly) in precalculus through elementary calculus courses. (Although it was written in 1999, I slightly modified it a few years later by including in the bibliography Havil's book **Gamma** which appeared in 2003 and an 1872 paper by Glaisher which I came across around 2003 or 2004.)

Comment: Dear @atmos we can also say in general that the if $g$ is the asymptotic expansion of $f$ around point $L$ then $\lim\limits_{x \to L} g(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to L} f(x)$, right?

Answer (score 0):

The limit gives you a single value. The asymptotics gives you a good approximation that is a function of the independent variable.

For example

$$\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x}$$ tends to zero, but by

$$\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x}=\frac2{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x}}\sim\frac1{\sqrt x},$$ we know how "fast".